# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.sql.CLOB: method getEmptyCLOB()Loracle/sql/CLOB; not found

Tags: java, oracle

> Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.sql.CLOB: method
>   getEmptyCLOB()Loracle/sql/CLOB; not found

I used the `oracle.sql.CLOB.empty_lob()` method in my java code (JDK 1.4.2) it returned Message:

> empty_lob() Deprecated message.

Then I used the `oracle.sql.CLOB.getEmptyCLOB()` then, faced the exception mentioned above

Comment: which oracle version are you using. `getEmptyCLOB()` implemented in 10.2 version.

Comment: And which driver version? You may have an incompatibility between your (ancient) Java version, the JDBC driver version, and your database version.

Comment: Version: Oracle JDBC Drivers release 10.2.0.1.0 production (10g R2)